# Are the source(s) of update for Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 different or the same?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, updates, ubuntu-gnome

I am contemplating installing Ubuntu GNOME and I am looking to educate myself more about the Ubuntu GNOME updates. I know updates regarding that of GNOME won't be found on Ubuntu 14.04, but I'm asking about security, system and application updates, do they get those same updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The exact same repositories are used for both. I believe that's one of the [requirements](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors) for official flavours for Ubuntu, and Ubuntu GNOME is an official flavour.

> I know updates regarding that of GNOME won't be found on Ubuntu 14.04

If an update from GNOME upstream reaches Ubuntu, it will available for both Ubuntu and Ubuntu GNOME. But such updates are rare for LTS releases.

Comment: some of them include extra repos for some compatability tweaks...I know there was something extra in kubuntu to allow tighter integration with kde that was installed by default but not present in the ubuntu repos because of some compatability issues

Comment: @sbergeron That belief requires sources for support. Kubuntu is nothing more and nothing less than ubuntu-standard + kubuntu-desktop.

Comment: @sbergeron yes you're right. I just read about it. maps, weather, photos etc.. you guys have been of substantial support today.

Comment: kubuntu is a ton more than ubuntu with just kde on top...I've used both and there is a lot that is different aside from even just the ui

Comment: @sbergeron READ: `kubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: that doesn't change lightdm, it doesn't change or replace many of the apps, nor does it implement some of the kubuntu specific kernel modifications that allow it to be ever so slightly less ram hogging in the official installation

Comment: I know for a fact the repos for ubuntu and ubuntu gnome are the same, along with the application set, but some of the other official versions do have different sources, and are more than just ubuntu with a different de

Comment: I believe...remember though that I'm saying this from something I read like 6 months ago here

Comment: @sbergeron Can you not read? `ubuntu-standard` + `kubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: I know what it says...I really thought I remembered something about there being something slightly different...sorry my bad